# Python Selenium - href link is not clickable, no matter which approach I use

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, href

I am trying to click on a link. However, no matter what I try it does not perform the actual action with selenium.

I have read all the stack overflow topics on this out there, but nothing seems to work for me. 
I have tried:

```
jcr = driver.find_element_by_id('JCRCategories')
jcr.click()
```

and

```
jcr = driver.find_element_by_id('JCRCategories')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(jcr).click(jcr).perform()
```

I have tried to find by xpath `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="JCRCategories"]')`

I have tried to find by css selector `# driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='RAMore.do?product=WOS&amp;search_mode=GeneralSearch&amp;SID=C2JQEWUF1Ig8CKQ3H8B&amp;qid=21&amp;ra_mode=more&amp;ra_name=JCRCategories&amp;colName=WOS&amp;viewType=raMore']").click()`

I have also tried with WebDriverWait

```
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'JCRCategories')))
    element.click()
```

I also tried to find by link text, but it doesn't work since that link text appears multiple times on the site. `driver.find_element_by_link_text("more options / values...").click()`

Here is the html

```
<a class="link-style1" id="JCRCategories" name="JCRCategories" href="RAMore.do?product=WOS&amp;search_mode=GeneralSearch&amp;SID=C2JQEWUF1Ig8CKQ3H8B&amp;qid=68&amp;ra_mode=more&amp;ra_name=JCRCategories&amp;colName=WOS&amp;viewType=raMore" onclick="return click_ra_more()" alt="More Refine Results" title="More Refine Results" tabindex="0" oncontextmenu="javascript:return IsAllowedRightClick(this);" hasautosubmit="true"> more options / values... </a>
```

Any help or tips is appreciated. See the screenshot for the website. 
[image: screenshot of website]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. It just doesn't interact with the element

Comment: Have you tried javascript executor to click?

Answer (score 0):

Update: driver.find_element_by_name() worked